# JavaScript regex help

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting strings with values such as `/Date(1)/` and `/Date(-99999)/`. The digits are variable length.

Wouldn't the regex just be this: `^/Date\(d+\)/$`

Comment: The purpose of your RegExp is to extract the timestamp, or just to test if the string matchs the pattern ?

Answer (score 3):

No, your regular expression is missing the optional minus in front of the digits (`\d`). You also need to escape the `/` as these are also the delimiter for regular expressions. Try this regular expression:

```
^/Date\(-?\d+\)/$
```

Either within the RegExp constructor:

```
new RegExp("^/Date\\(-?\\d+\\)/$")
```

Or as literal:

```
/^\/Date\(-?\d+\)\/$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You're not allowing for the possibility of a leading hyphen, and your slashes are a little wonky.

```
/^Date\(-?\d+\)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are getting JSON Date values serialized by [ASP .NET](http://encosia.com/2009/04/27/how-i-handle-json-dates-returned-by-aspnet-ajax/), the slashes are included on the strings, to capture the timestamp you can simply match the optional minus sign and any digit character sequence:

```
var date = "\/Date(1240718400000)\/";
var timeStamp = date.match(/-?\d+/)[0]; // 1240718400000;
```

Or a more restrictive one:

```
var timeStamp = date.match(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//)[1];
```